# how to get unique row in sql from one column which same value in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a contract which has 2 different names but has the same number, and I really want to get only one result which that phone number show up for my result though their name is different

example, in my database I have a column called name and phoneNumber :

```
1. name : John, phoneNumber: 123;
2. name : Dion, phoneNumber: 123;
```

I really want to get the result only one which only shows the new one and unique, I could implementation it by `SELECT DISTINCT .....` so I will only get unique, I was trying `SELECT DISTINCT name, phoneNumber FROM Contacts*`

but the result show those data because they have a different name, I really the result only show up the one only which latest in database

I have DTO( DATA TRANSFER OBJECT) like this

```
public ContactsDTO {
   private String name;
   private String phoneNumber;
}
```

I really when I use JPA to get data I could convert that DTO to be Model, it gonna something like this :

```
[Contact(name="John", phoneNumber="123")];
```

i was using JPA like this 
List findDistinctByPhoneNumber();
but it is error,

and when i use

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINC new map(C.name as name, C.phoneNumber as phonenumber) from Contact C")
List<Contact> findDistnctByPhoneNumber();
```

the result of that is like this 
`[{name: "John", phone number:"123"}]`
that is the only array of the object inside that array, I do love yo get the model which I something like this :

```
 [Contact(name="John", phoneNumber="123")];
```

Comment: `.setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();`?

Comment: i am new for JPA and Spring Boot, can u write the code for that ? please,

Comment: Ofc. My wage is USD 200/hr.

Comment: Do you have an id in your table contact , i mean a primary key whitch type is number?

Comment: yes it extends from Base @TinyOS

Comment: So you want to group by numberPhone then you get the recent one whitch has the recent id ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your entity look like :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Contact {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    // constcutors && getters && setters
}
```

The repository:

```
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long> {
}
```

The main test:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ExampleH2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ExampleH2Application.class, args);
        ContactRepository contactRepository = context.getBean(ContactRepository.class);
        // save datas
        contactRepository.saveAndFlush(new Contact("John", "123"));
        contactRepository.saveAndFlush(new Contact("Dion", "123"));
        contactRepository.saveAndFlush(new Contact("Albert", "548"));

        List<Contact> res=new ArrayList<>();
        // group by phoneNumber then select max id -> recent
        Function<Contact, String> groupingComponent = Contact::getPhoneNumber;
        List<Contact> list = contactRepository.findAll();
        Collection<List<Contact>> collect = list.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(groupingComponent)).values();
        collect.parallelStream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(e-> res.add(Collections.max(e, Comparator.comparing(Contact::getId))));
    }
}
```

The result look like :

> [Contact [id=3, name=Albert, phoneNumber=548], Contact [id=2,
>   name=Dion, phoneNumber=123]]

NB: may be there is an easy way to do that in nativeQuery, but i am no expert in :(

Comment: sorry! i do not understand your comment !